# Connect Django to remote mysql server on a local network

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have setup Django and am a complete newb. I have successfully connected to a mysql database on my localhost but have had trouble connecting to a database that's hosted on another machine on my local network.

Localhost is: 192.168.1.51 (aka "laptop")
Remote is: 192.168.1.50 (aka "desktop")

settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'mydb',                      
        'USER': 'root',                      
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',                  
        'HOST': '192.168.1.50',                      
        'PORT': '3306',                      
    }
}
```

I run 'python manage.py runserver' and get an error:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'laptop.local' (using password: YES)")

I've granted access to 'root@laptop' but I can't figure out why it is adding '.local'....Am I doing this right?

Comment: Are able to login to mysql with the same credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In default, root account only can be used to login to mysql locally. You need give root user logon permission from the host at first.

Comment: I've granted access to root@laptop and access to root@laptop.local....is that what you mean?

Comment: @oldmonk : please give little more explanation