# Django - Can we make a connection to different remote database

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, mysql-python, remote-server

I am writing a Django application where I already have 1 mysql backend db configured in my settings.py.

I know we can add as many db configurations as we want, but that's `hard coding` which I don't want.. rather can't possibly do as I have to ad-hockly connect to say, about 70-80 different remote machines and query and fetch the result.

I am planning to connect to those machines via their `IP address`.

I am comparatively new to `Django`, so I was wondering if we can somehow, make a `function` which queries the machine by putting in configuration something like :

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'dbName',
    'USER': 'root',                     
    'PASSWORD': 'root',                  
    'HOST': '',                      
    'PORT': '3306'
  }
}
```

So instead of `DATABASES and default`, I could configure my function to change the configuration, through an `Ajax call` or something!

Fortunately, every machine I have to connect to uses `mysql` so no problem with that.
I looked into [this mysql -python connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-install.html) but not sure if I should use it as I already have `MySQLDb` installed. I also have to do some `raw queries` too :|

Could anyone guide me for what would be the best approach for this situation?

P.S : I have also looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945128/connect-django-to-remote-mysql-server-on-a-local-network) which discusses about connecting to remote mysql machine from local. But that's of no help for me :( :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are quite a few paths you can take, 3 of which are:

1. Add all your connections in `DATABASES` using [`using`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset) - which you said you don't want to do because you have so many conections
2. You could connect using python's mysql library.  If you do this I don't think you'll get to use djangos nice ORM
3. Look at how django wraps connections to allow you to use their ORM.  I did some quick searches about manually establishing a connection using django ORM but didn't find anything.  All the answers are in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/utils.py).  I believe you can just instantiate your own connections and interact with your remote database using the ORM.  I don't have time to look through it now, but everything is in their source

Comment: Wow, I can instantiate the remote database and use Django's ORM? If that's possible, I would consider that to be even more beautiful than my girlfriend! In `Java`, it's like just couple of lines of codes and hola!, you can configure any connections as you want! Thanks @dm03514 for providing the link, will look into it. One more question here is, if I make use of `python's mysql library`, can I still make use of `Django's ORM` for my configured objects and just query to my remote databases using `raw sql queries`? Thanks again!